# Java - Deque manual - Remove Last

Tags: java, deque

I've got some homework to in java to implement a deque system. I've created the other methods and they pass my tests. However I'm having a issue with removing the last one. I have this so far;

```
//remove the element at the back of the deque
public int removeBack()
{
    int size = a.size();
    size--;

    if( size > 0 )
    {
        int last = a.get(size);
        last--;
        a.remove(last);
    }

    size = a.size();

    return size;
}
```

Here is the JQuery test it fails on.

```
    Deque d = new Deque(1);
    d.insertBack(1);
    assertEquals(1, d.length());
    int b = d.removeBack();
    assertEquals(0, b);
    // java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<1> but was:<0>
```

Anyone have any ideas? I really can't see where I'm going wrong with this one.

Cheers

Comment: `assertEquals(0, d.length());`  - shouldn't the length be 1 here already?

Comment: (which would indicate your insert is not working yet, either!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is a mess.

```
d.insertBack(1);   <---- you add one element.
assertEquals(0, d.length()); <--- length is expected to be 1
int b = d.removeBack();  <---- you remove one element, and return the new length (!)
assertEquals(1, b); <----- b = length after removing = 0
```

What you probably meant to do:

```
public int removeBack() {
    return a.remove(a.size() - 1); // Remove and return last element.
}
```

(Note: it is standard to return the last element, not the list size, which can be queried by `size()` when necessary.)

Comment: Okay, now you still misunderstood `remove`. It uses an index. Otherwise, **which should it remove if there were duplicate numbers in the list?**

Comment: Actually, there is a [`remove(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29), that removes the first occurrence from the list. Although, I strongly agree that this particular `remove` should be the [other one](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove%28int%29), accepting the index.

Comment: I know, that is why I asked him: it would not remove the last element, but e.g. in `1 2 3 4 1` it would remove the first.

Answer (score 0):

The following looks iffy:

```
    int last = a.get(size);
    last--;
    a.remove(last);
```

I don't see how this can work regardless of whether you're expecting [`ArrayList.remove(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove%28int%29) to take an index or a value (it takes an index).

Comment: Oh yeah, .get gets the actuall element it'self rather than the position of the element correct?

Comment: I just took a look, so unless I miss read it. My presumption above was correct and it gets the value of the element rather than the index of the element. Thus meaning getting last is not needed?